# How to apply media query?

Tags: html, css

I have created a site using HTML and CSS. The site is currently not responsive and  I need to change into a responsive one. I have used media queries but it doesn't seem to be working. Are there any mistakes in my code? I have applied media queries to the entire CSS. Should I apply media query to the entire CSS or only a particular part of the CSS?

I tried using the media query `@media screen and (max-width: 300px) { }` and it works when resizing the browser but after that when the browser is maximized again the desktop style is not getting applied.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  body {
    font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    /* it's good practice to zero the margin and padding of the body element to account for differing browser defaults */
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #container {
    width: 800px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* the auto margins (in conjunction with a width) center the page */
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    text-align: left;
    /* this overrides the text-align:
center on the body element. */
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #header {
    background: #DDDDDD;
    padding: 0 10px;
    /* this padding matches the left alignment of the elements in the divs that appear beneath it. If an image is used in the #header instead
of text, you may want to remove the padding. */
    background-image: url(images/top.png);
    height: 160px;
  }
  #top_menu {
    color: #e5e491;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: -20px;
    width: auto;
    float: right;
    margin: 90px 0 -50px 0;
  }
  #top_login {
    color: #e5e491;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0px 0 0px 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -160px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #header h1 {
    margin: 0;
    /* zeroing the margin of the last element in
the #header div will avoid margin collapse - an unexplainable space between divs. If the div has a border around it, this is not necessary as that also avoids the margin collapse */
    padding: 0px 0;
    /* using padding instead of margin will allow you to
keep the element away from the edges of the div */
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    height: 160px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar1 {
    float: left;
    width: 16em;
    /* since this element is floated, a width must be given */
    background: #75b808;
    /* top and bottom padding create visual space within this div */
    margin: 15px 10px 15px 15px;
    background-image: url(images/news_top.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 15px 2px 2px 2px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar2 {
    float: right;
    width: 17em;
    /* since this element is floated, a width must be given */
    background: #EBEBEB;
    /* the background color will be displayed for the length of the content in the column, but no further */
    padding: 10px 0;
    /* top and bottom padding create visual
space within this div */
    border: #0a4b67;
    border-width: thick;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar1 h3,
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar1 p,
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar2 p,
  .thrColElsHdr #sidebar2 h3 {
    margin-left: 10px;
    /* the left and right margin
should be given to every element that will be placed in the side columns */
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #mainContent {
    margin: 0 12em 0 1em;
    /* the right margin can be given in ems or pixels. It creates the space down the right side of the page.
*/
    color: #0a4b67;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #mainContent h2 h3 h4 {
    color: #0a4b67;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #footer {
    padding: 0 10px;
    /* this padding matches the left alignment of the elements in the divs that appear above it. */
    background: #E1E994;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #line {
    padding: 0 10px;
    /* this padding matches the left alignment of the elements in the divs that appear above it. */
    background: #E1E994;
    margin-top: 0px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #footer p {
    margin: 0;
    /* zeroing the margins of the first element in the footer will
avoid the possibility of margin collapse - a space between divs */
    padding: 10px 0;
    /* padding on this element will create space, just as the the margin would have, without the margin collapse issue */
  }
  /* Miscellaneous classes for reuse */
  .fltrt {
    /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }
  .fltlft {
    /* this class can be used to float an element left in your
page */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
  }
  .clearfloat {
    /* this class should be placed on a div or break element and should be the final element before the close of a container that should fully contain a float */
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #container #header #top_menu_logo {
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-right: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 0em;
    margin-left: 0em;
    float: left;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #container #header #top_menu a {
    color: #e5e491;
  }
  .thrColElsHdr #container #subheading {
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 211px;
  }
  div#nifty {
    font-size: 12px;
    background: #2d6482;
    width: 300px;
  }
  div.rounded div {
    height: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  #radiusx,
  #radiusy {
    text-align: right;
    width: 20px;
  }
  div#nifty p {
    color: #dfe791;
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 2px;
  }
  #thetext {
    float: right;
    width: 380px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #theimg {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
  }
}
</style>




please any idea any mistake  please comment my question ?
```

Comment: Is this your full CSS? or just your CSS for `300px width`. You need your global CSS and then below that what you want to change when the screen width changes, this is where you use your media query

Comment: i have used media top of css code sir@Andrew

Comment: You want us to 'debug' you code to check if it's *working*?

Comment: no sir  i want doubt  i need to apply media query full css or particular part css?  thats i have doubt.even i used media query @media screen and (max-width: 300px) { } its working when  re size browser after that max mize browser  desktop style not showing

Comment: You only use a media query on what you want to change/adapt at a screen width. You dont use it for the full CSS

Comment: hmm thank you @andrew. if i used media changes css code. after  that  i need to  copy changes code and  paste without media query?

Comment: I have reworded the content and corrected grammar mistakes to make the question clearer and have also added the information that you had provided in the comments as response. Always add all relevant information into the question itself by editing instead of leaving them in comments. Comments tend to go unnoticed at times.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do media queries is this:

```
/* rules that apply regardless of resolution */
.some > .css > .selector {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /* rules that apply for screens >= 1440px */
    .some > .css > .selector {
        width: 1280px;
        color: rgb(144, 144, 144);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and (max-width: 1439px) {
    /* rules that apply for screens 1024px - 1439px */
    .some > .css > .selector {
        width: 920px;
        color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 640px) and (max-width: 1023px) {
    /* rules that apply for screens 640px - 1023px */
    .some > .css > .selector {
        width: 500px;
        color: rgb(64, 64, 64);
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
    /* rules that apply for screens 639px and below */
    .some > .css > .selector {
        width: 300px;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

Alter the conditions with your desired breakpoints, of course. 
As a guideline, always apply your media queries after your style for that element / logical section of elements. This makes it convenient later on to find and edit your styles for a particular element across all resolutions.

A few things to note for first-timers:

- ensure that you use px values that don't overlap in the media queries.
- the rules within media queries will "overwrite" those outside of it.

Answer (score -1):

You should do a link tag for the css and have this meta tag
and your

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {}
```

does not make sense because then you will choose a screen that's smaller than 300px width

```
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 460px) {}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"/>
```

Comment: its add my html code i have updated my css code here

Comment: Are you selecting screen size thats smaller than 300px in width?

Comment: 320 i have selected screen size i have used  media query @media screen and (max-width: 300px) { }

Comment: Then you should set it to @media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

Comment: Does not make sense because you are selecting a screen size thats smaller then 300px i am guessing that you are selecting for a low res phone?

Comment: k what i will set screen size ?  sir

Comment: @media screen and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 460px) {}